# Create in another workbook cells depending on each other

Tags: excel, vba

my problem is in theory simple, but maybe not in practice.

The idea is to create a macro that takes data from a workbook, elaborates them, and write results in another workbook. **However**, I want the cells in this new workbook depend on each other.

For example. In the new WB, let us suppose that I write in cell A1 the number 1 (one). I'd like to assign the cell A2 such that depends on the value in A1 (ex. =A1+1) and, when the WB is saved and closed, this dependence remains such that the user can re-open the file, modify the value in A1 and see the value in A2 modified too.

Is it possible to do that? Which is the best way?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can.  But, you need to keep open the second workbook in order to save the changes.  I would do it binding the trigger to an event like `Workbook_AfterSave` or `Worbook_BeforeClose`.

Comment: I don't understand. I keep the 2nd WB open until I finish to write data. Then, the WB is saved and then closed. Could you post me an example?

Comment: Just write formula's to the new book dynamically; you don't have to copy just values across